# Ionic v1 - Select side menu template based on $rootScope.lang variable

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing an application that supports English & Arabic languages.
Well, currently am facing a situation of switching the hamburger menu(left) and home(right) buttons on switching the language (to Arabic) and the menu toggle conditions as well.
So I would like to know if it is possible to select side menu abstract template based on a rootScope variable in ionic v1.
As the `config` function is executed first, we wont be receiving the rootScope variables to select the template based on the rootScope variable.

Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: you could include the child template in the main template with ng-if which can be used by rootscope variable

Comment: @GauravSrivastava I tried the same, but while switch from English->Arabic, it switches the menu as expected. But switching back from Arabic->English, the menu header hides.

Comment: please make a plunkar for your problem

Comment: Let me see if i can make a plunker and expect the same issue in plunker.

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/jpp9nJ/ 
Please check this plunker. In this the content slides to both sides when language is switched and the menu buttons change as expected. But in my app the menu header bar itself gets hidden along with sliding both side after switching language.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava, Did you came to look into the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.!!

Placing `ng-if` for `<ion-nav-bar>` didn't helped me. I think the framework is not reloading the `<ion-nav-bar>` on language switch (Please clear me). So I came up with `ng-include` directive in the `ion-side-menu-content` with two `<ion-nav-bar>` templates for English and Arabic and that worked.